# How can any single-threaded program be a valid multithreaded program?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I was reading the book "Java Concurrency In Practice". In second chapter, I read the statement

> any single-threaded program is also a valid multithreaded program

I could not understand this statement.

Kindly share your thoughts on it so that my confusion can be cleared.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the statement doesn't imply that any correct single threaded program is also correct multi threaded program, the author simply states that it is possible to transform any single threaded program to be executed in multi-threaded environment.

However, if the program is already not **correct** in single threaded environment then it cannot possibly be correct in more complex multi threaded environment.

From the book:

> Since any single threaded program is also a valid multithreaded
>   program, it cannot be thread safe if it is not even correct in a
>   single threaded environment.
>
> If an object is correctly implemented, no sequence of operations-calls
>   to public methods and reads or writes of public fields should be able
>   to violate any of its invariants or post conditions. No set of
>   operations performed sequentially or concurrently on instances of a
>   thread safe class can cause an instance to be in an invalid state.

And this:

> If the loose use of "correctness" here bothers you, you may prefer to
>   think of a thread safe class as one that is no more broken in a
>   concurrent environment than in a single threaded environment.

@yshavit
*Before you go off thinking about multithreaded correctness, make sure you at least have single-threaded correctness.*

Comment: In a nutshell: before you go off thinking about multithreaded correctness, make sure you at least have single-threaded correctness. You can't be correct in a multithreaded context if you're not already correct in a single-threaded context, and single-threaded is an easier problem.

Comment: thank you for the comment, that is more concise explanation than mine so i would add it to the answer :)

Comment: @John It looks like this question has been left unattended by you for many months. There are two answers to your question already. Do accept one of them as the correct answer by clicking the tick mark next to the answer or comment on the answers for further clarification.

Answer (score 3):

> any single-threaded program is also a valid multithreaded program

What this basically means is that any single threaded program can be used in a multi-threaded context. Take the following code for example :

```
class A {
    public void doSomething() {  }
}
```

If we consider the above class in isolation, it is clearly a single threaded program; however, the same program can be used in a multi-threaded context as well :

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {  public void run() { A a = new A(); a.doSomething(); } }).start();
Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {  public void run() { A a = new A(); a.doSomething(); } }).start();
```

---

Talking about a specific related paragraph in the book that you didn't ask about but would be worth discussing :

> No set of operations performed sequentially or concurrently on
>   instances of a thread-safe class can cause an instance to be in an
>   invalid state

Let's add some state to our class :

```
class A {
    int iCantBeNegative = 10;
    public void doSomething() { --icantBeNegative;  }
}
```

The expectation of the programmer was that `iCantBeNegative` should never be less than zero and yet, they did nothing to enforce this requirement. Since this program is primarily incorrect in a single-threaded context from the point of view of expectations (`iCantBeNegatvie` will be < 0 if `doSomething` is called 11 times or more in a row), it is most definitely incorrect in a multi-threaded context.

Answer (score 1):

> "any single-threaded program is also a valid multithreaded program"

Without going to the book and reading the section, there are many ways that a single threaded application is really a multithreaded one when running in a JVM.  There are a number of JVM specific threads that are forked when the JVM starts.  They include gc threads, finalizer, JMX threads (if enabled), and others.  These threads run in the background to help the JVM operate efficiently.

For example, on my OSX box, the following threads are forked by default:

- main
- Reference Handler
- Finalizer
- Signal Dispatcher
- Attach listener
- A number of RMI and JMX threads if JMX is enabled

Also, as the main thread running the user application code encounters `synchronized` blocks or accesses `volatile` fields in libraries or the JDK, then the main thread goes through memory barriers, acquires and releases locks, etc. just like a multithreaded application does.  That may be what the author was referencing.

Lastly, it is important to realize that the term "reentrant" was created before the concept of threads was even invented.  Code needed to be properly written to be reentrant because of recursive methods or interrupt handlers which meant that the code could be entered twice even though it was never by multiple "threads".  This need to write proper reentrant code was necessary before the context switch, swap in/out, cache memory, etc.. Yeah I'm showing my age here.